# Is it safe to edit python modules while running a program

Tags: python

I have a python program. The program is written such that it uses all the python modules present from the beginning of execution.

I have two terminal windows open: in the first window I can edit the code and do short test runs, and in the second window I run the same program (modules of which are added to the PYTHONPATH) with such parameters that it runs for several hours.

Question: is it safe to start the execution in the second window, and then to switch to the first window and modify the code and do some short test runs? I start to modify some time after the beginning of the execution in the second window. Also, is it safe to switch git branches in such situation?

Comment: Yes. Python compiles your code before it interprets it, you're fine (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916729/how-exactly-is-python-bytecode-run-in-cpython ). As long as you're not doing dynamic source code compilation of any kind, which I think you'd know if you were

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189859/how-does-python-read-and-interpret-source-files